# PHP inheritance from grandparent

Tags: php, inheritance

I am trying to understand how PHP inheritance works in terms of "protected static function".

Say we have 3 classes (A, B, C), where C inherits from B, and B from A:

```
class A{
    # ... properties & methods
    # then we have targetFunc()
    protected static function grandparentFn(){
        // some action
    }
}
class B extends A{
    protected static function parentFn(){
        // some action
    }
}
class C extends B{

}
```

When i do:

```
C::parentFn() // it fails .... (expected, due to protected)
```

Then when I do:

```
C::grandparentFn() // it works .... ????
```

Isn't `grandparentFn()` protected? How come it is accessible as described above? Even for a static method, how is visibility applied here?

Comment: Why do you think _it works_? https://3v4l.org/jiOYl

Comment: trust me, i don't think it should work, but i tried it, and it worked......

Comment: Trust the execution, on ALL versions of PHP, unless you have modified and compiled your own PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inheriting and parent classes. This applies to static protected methods as well.

So when you want to access static protected method you can do it only from inside the class, parent class or child class.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score -2):

It won't work : `Call to protected method A::grandparentFn() from context '' in [...][...]:18`

An example can be found here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc1750647f242840ef9a3606692ddaef8e906648